# Ways to improve foll. Java code

Tags: java

Any ways to improve the foll. code block :

```
public class MyUnits {
    public static String MILLSECONDS = "milliseconds";
    public static String SECONDS = "seconds";
    public static String MINUTES = "minutes";
    public static String HOURS = "hours";

    public int quantity;
    public String units;

    public MyUnits(int quantity, String units) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.units = units;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return (quantity + " " + units);
    }

    // Test code
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new MyUnits(1, MyUnits.MILLSECONDS));
        System.out.println(new MyUnits(2, MyUnits.SECONDS));
        System.out.println(new MyUnits(3, MyUnits.MINUTES));
        System.out.println(new MyUnits(4, MyUnits.HOURS));
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In which way? What is your goal? Performance? Readability? Obfuscation?

Comment: Please note that Java already has its own TimeUnit class in java.util.concurrent.

Comment: @Daniel : Not in any particular way. Just, in general, ways to improve code.

Answer (score 3):

The static ints should be final. The usual modifier for a "constant" in Java is

```
public static final <Type> <name> = <value>;
```

A bigger enhancement: exchange the static int with enum:

```
public enum Unit {MILLISECOND, SECOND, MINUTE, HOUR}
```

The new constructor signature would be:

```
public MyUnits(int quantity, Unit unit) { ... }
```

The non-static fields in MyUnit should be made private. Add getter/setter methods for access.

And finally (and for serious code only), I'd separate the test code from the class. Have a look at testing frameworks, like `junit` and implement separate test classes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Mark your `public static` variables
   as `final`; better yet, use enums.
2. Don't let instance variables (`quantity`, `units`) be `public`. Provide "getter" methods to read their values. Consider **not** providing "setter" methods to change their values. This makes your class immutable, which can make it easier to use (the state of an immutable object is much more predictable than that of a mutable object!)
3. Be more specific about what the code
   is intended to do; then make it do
   that. (This also allows you to ask
   more specific questions, which would
   get you better answers.)
4. Add comments, especially [javadoc
   comments](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html).

Answer (score 0):

use [enum](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) for the unit within your class.

```
public enum MyUnit {
MILLSECONDS(1, "milliseconds"), SECOND(2, "seconds"),
MINUTES(3,"minutes"), HOURS(4, "hours");



private MyUnit(int quantity, String units) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.units = units;
}

private int quantity;
private  String units;

public String toString() {
    return (quantity + " " + units);
}
    /*getters setters*/
}
```

and just call like that

```
MyUnit.HOURS.getUnits();
MyUnit.HOURS.getCuantity();
```

Comment: Removed +1, because you don't know what enums are, and the quantity seems to be arbitrary in his implementation.

Comment: @Daniel - disagree, hilal knows pretty well how to use enums. OTH, agree, because the OP's concept of "MyUnit" was different - he wanted to create objects to describe "a quantity of something", like "4 milliseconds" or "25 milliseconds".

Comment: hilal: Sorry, you know what enum are. Simple the kind how you used them would not allow other quantities. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Add clone(), hashcode() and equals(), and implement Comparable, Serializable and Cloneable.

Remove the test code and move it to a test class. Use JUnit for testing.

Write a function `public Date addToDate(Date date)`.

Comment: I'd upvote if you take out Serializable and Cloneable -- definitely take out Cloneable!!

Comment: read this ... http://www.xenoveritas.org/blog/xeno/java_copy_constructors_and_clone ... for example.

Comment: This article shows, what you can do wrong, and makes clone() only a bad idea if there are final fields, or the subclasses miss to implement clone(), too. His "Solution" is to use copy constructors, but thse could also be missed by subclasses. I really can't agree with the author, so Cloneable() stays in my list (even if I like copy constructors more), and no +1.