# Why can't I declare and initialize static variable in inner class?

Tags: java, class, static, final, nested-class

class A is the outer class. Class B is an inner class of A, and class C is an inner class of B.

All three classes declare and initialize one static final variable.

This is the object in class A:

```
static final Object x = new Object();
```

class B:

```
static final Object x1 = new Object();
```

class C:

```
static final Object x2 = new Object();
```

The problem is that the variable in class A compiles fine, but in B and C the variable does not.

**Error message:**

> the field can not be declare static; static field only declared in
>   static and top level type

The `String`, and `int` in class B and C doesn't receive an error.

Complete code:

```
class A {
  static final Object x = new Object();
  static final String s = "s1";
  static final int y = 1;

  class B {
    static final Object x1 = new Object();
    static final String s1 = "s1";
    static final int y1 = 1;

     class C {
      static final Object x2 = new Object();
      static final String s2 = "s1";
      static final int y2 = 1;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5642851/3377857

Comment: its working when remove static final Object x2 = new Object(); statements program compile and run also but when add this statement come compile time error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have static fields/method in a regular inner classes, because, inner classes will work only with instance of outer classes.

So, static can't be there with instances.

But they can have compile time constants, check [JLS 8.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3). You `x`, `x1`, `x2` are not compile time constants, while `s1`, `s2`, `y1`, `y2` are compile time constants

> Inner classes may not declare static initializers (§8.7) or member
>   interfaces, or a compile-time error occurs.
>
> **Inner classes may not declare static members, unless they are constant variables (§4.12.4), or a compile-time error occurs.**

Comment: I am curious as to how you can have an _implicitly_ static nested class...

Comment: but when remove the these type statement static final Object x2 = new Object(); and program compile but also have static fields int and String

Comment: @user3184306 : Check my updated answer, inner classes can have static compile time constants

Answer (score -2):

You can just make the inner classes `static`.

```
static class A {

    static final Object x = new Object();
    static final String s = "s1";
    static final int y = 1;

    static class B {

        static final Object x1 = new Object();
        static final String s1 = "s1";
        static final int y1 = 1;

        static class C {

            static final Object x2 = new Object();
            static final String s2 = "s1";
            static final int y2 = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Although obviously this will make some other things difficult.