# Why does this static property in Processing (Java) raise an error?

Tags: java, oop, processing

Here is my class in Processing ...

```
class Stripe {

  PShape s;
  float x, y, w;

  static Stripe lastStripe;


  Stripe() {
    x = width / 2;
    y = 0;
    w = 150;
    s = createShape();
    s.beginShape();
    s.fill(0);
    s.noStroke();
    s.vertex(w, 0);
    s.bezierVertex(w + 50, height * 1/4, w - 50 , height * 1/3, w, height); 
    s.vertex(0, height);
    s.bezierVertex(-50, height * 1/3, 50 , height * 1/4, 0, 0); 
    //s.vertex(0, 0);


    //s.bezierVertex(50, 50, 50, 50, 100, 100); 
    s.endShape(CLOSE);
  }

  void draw() {
    pushMatrix();
    translate(x, y);
    shape(s);
    popMatrix();

  }

  void move() {
    x = x + STRIPE_VEL;

    if (x > (width + OFFSCREEN_BUFFER)) {
      x =  Stripe.lastStripe.x - STRIPE_SPACING;
      Stripe.lastStripe = this;
    }

  }

}
```

When I try and compile I get the following error ...

> The field lastStripe can only be declared static; static fields can only be declared in static or top level types

Looking at this [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html), this seems to be a valid Java pattern. Although the code above is self referential, it still raises the same error if the type is changed to an `int` or similar.

What is the problem here?

EDIT: By request, here is the rest of the sketch which is in another tab. I'm starting to think that the Processing way is to just declare such variables as a 'global' rather than a static variable on a class ... I'll probably just do that.

```
float STRIPE_VEL = 0.5;
float OFFSCREEN_BUFFER = 500;
float STRIPE_SPACING = 50;

int numStripes = 0;

Stripe[] stripes;


void setup() {

  float offset = 0;
  size(800, 600, P2D);
  smooth();

  numStripes = (width + 2 * OFFSCREEN_BUFFER) / STRIPE_SPACING;
  stripes = new Stripe[numStripes];

  for (int i=0; i < numStripes; i++) {
    stripes[i] = new Stripe();
    stripes[i].x = offset;
    offset = offset + inc;
  }
  Stripe.lastStripe = stripes[0];

}


void draw() {
  background(255);

  for (int i=0; i < numStripes; i++) {
    stripes[i].draw();
    stripes[i].move();
  }

  //blurAll();


}
```

Comment: By the error message, seems that this class is a nested class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I declare and initialize static variable in inner class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297722/why-cant-i-declare-and-initialize-static-variable-in-inner-class)

Comment: This is a 'top level' class in Processing i.e. in a separate tab, but maybe Processing on compilation embeds it in another class, I don't know. I have no experience of Java, but I do know C# pretty well and yeah I wouldn't program like this in C#, but Processing is geared in a C like way.

Comment: Just so you know this isn't pure Java, it is a domain specific language [Processing](http://processing.org/) which wraps up Java in a 'friendly' way. Of course it means that you get the DSL problem of programming in one language and getting error/debug info in another ...

Comment: Is this your entire sketch? If not, can you post the whole thing?

Comment: @user2864740:  This doesn't feel like a duplicate.  Processing is a slightly different animal than Java, and there are things that it does behind the scenes.  This is one of those which is burning the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try renaming the specific file i.e Stripe.pde to Stripe.java. You are right in your comment there: "Processing on compilation embeds it in another class", actually all the tabs in a processing sketch are wrapped around a big java (top-level) class... So, renaming one of them to .java will force it to be a top level class!

Answer (score 1):

Change your inner class `Stripe` to be declared as a `static` (inner) class:

```
static class Stripe {
  ...
}
```

This will make sure `Stripe` does not require an instance of the enclosing class per instance of `Stripe`, and you will be able to create *class variables* (static fields).

---

As a side note, it is always a better practice to make an inner class `static`, if it does not actually need an instance of the enclosing class.

Comment: Hmm thanks, so when trying this I get the further error that `Cannot make a static reference to non-static field width`. This would  imply that `width` and the other 'globals' in Processing are implemented as an instance variable of some invisible container class?

Comment: @Brendan They are instance variables of the enclosing class, you need to choose - having static fields, or being able to access enclosing class fields, you cannot have both..