# Java: Is it possible to make try/catch shorter?

Tags: java, try-catch, thread-sleep

For example:

```
try {
        Thread.sleep(333);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

can I use the above try/catch in some kind of way using a created method like `trySleep(Thread.sleep(333));` that'll do the exact same as the original try?

A example of use:

```
public class Test implements Runnable {

    public Test() {
        Thread thisThread = new Thread(this);
        thisThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true){
            System.out.println("Testing");
            trySleep(Thread.sleep(333));
        }
    }

    public void trySleep(/*Thread object*/){
        //Code for try/catch
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

}
```

Of course the above code won't compile, it's just for the question.

The reason I want this kinda thing is because I find the try/catch things to be so messy and is quiet annoying to read.

Comment: What are your reasons for not inlining this statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap `Thread.sleep` in a function that re-throws any exception as a runtime exception (or any uncaught exception).

```
public static void trySleep(long millis) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(millis);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted during sleep", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I alway thought that the Thread.sleep had to be in the Thread it was running in? For like if you call it in the construtor `Test()` it wouldn't work.

Comment: @FOD When you call `trySleep` from inside `run` you're calling it in the current thread. It doesn't matter where the function is defined.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the question. If you add the three lines into the trySleep-method Body, you get a method, which will let the Thread sleep.

So the answer is yes.

By the way:
You wrote an endless sleeping loop

Comment: I know it was endless, it was just a quick example I chose to made, anything else in the example would of been pointless and unrelated.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @HarshalPatil: The part about "If you add the three lines into the trySleep-method" was the answer. I had some problem with the question, because the answer was included to the question.

Comment: Ohh i thought it is just comment anyways up

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this, but not exactly the way you describe it now. Wherever you use `Thread.sleep()` you will have to catch `InterruptedException`, so you would have to enclose the call in the method like this:

```
public void trySleep(long ms) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(ms);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); //handle exception here
    }
}
```

You can call this method like this: `trySleep(333)`

It is sometimes better to just add a throws declaration to your method though or to re-throw a more meaningful exception, unless you know that this is the location where it makes most sense to catch the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your sleeping code in another method as you sugested.

```
public static void trySleep(Thread target, long millis){
    try{
        target.sleep(millis);
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
         System.err.println("Exception Occurred while trying to sleep!");
    }
}
```

You probably shoud do this, in fact, as making code modular is the right way to go.

Comment: The `target` parameter is redundant and misleading because [`Thread.sleep(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) is a static method that causes the _current_ thread to sleep. For readability's sake, static methods should not be called through instance references.

Answer (score 0):

One important thing I think you really need to consider (in addition to the answers to how to do this properly), is to understand what code you're calling.

In your code:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (true){
        System.out.println("Testing");
        trySleep(Thread.sleep(333));
    }
}
```

Particularly this line:

```
trySleep(Thread.sleep(333));
```

You're basically saying

- Call the method Thread.sleep() with a value of 333.
- Whatever value Thread.sleep() returns, pass that to another method.

But [the Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) say it's a void method.

Also in your code:

```
public void trySleep(/*Thread object*/){
    //Code for try/catch
}
```

You should check [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642834/why-should-the-static-field-be-accessed-in-a-static-way) out for why this is not good practice (as you'll be trying to invoke a static method on an instance object).

Others have answered your question on this, but I highly recommend brushing up on these areas as it indicates you may likely be missing critical knowledge of some important concepts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java 8's lambda expressions to do something similar to this:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface InterruptedExceptionRunnable {
    void run() throws InterruptedException;
}

void trySleep(InterruptedExceptionRunnable exRunnable) {
    try {
        exRunnable.run();
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

which allows you to write this:

```
trySleep(()->Thread.sleep(333));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do basically this with Java 8 lambdas.

```
class Example {
    @FunctionalInterface
    interface InterruptableRunnable {
        void run() throws InterruptedException;
    }

    static void tryRun(InterruptableRunnable r) {
        try {
            r.run();
        } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // passing a lambda
                tryRun( () -> Thread.sleep(333) );
            }
        });

        t.start();
        // passing a method reference
        tryRun(t::join);
    }
}
```