# Change Icon of OptionPane dialog

Tags: java, joptionpane

Ok, enough playing guys, today I'm gonna challenge you big:

So I have an option dialog and want to change the icon of the dialog on the right side so instead of showing a default red cross it will show me a question icon.
Is there a basic library in Java that might return me an Icon object for the JOptionPane constructor?

Thanks!!

```
JOptionPane option=new JOptionPane();
option.showOptionDialog(mainFrame, "Choose shape type", null, 0, 0, null, new String [] {"Lines only","Bounded shapes"}, null);
```

Comment: Note that `showOptionDialog` is a static method - no need to create an instance of JOptionPane and [access in a non-static manner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642834/why-should-the-static-field-be-accessed-in-a-static-way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you don't use something like this: there is icon option JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE

```
JOptionPane option=new JOptionPane();
option.showOptionDialog(mainFrame, "Choose shape type", null, 0, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, new String [] {"Lines only","Bounded shapes"}, null);
```

Comment: It makes sense, I tried it, but the thing is the constructor expects Icon object - not int.

Comment: Ooops, tried it in wrong argument... Works.. Thanks!