# non-static method error, how to fix?

Tags: java

I have been getting the error message "non-static method getCountAirports() cannot be referenced from a static context" How do I fix this error in Airport.java  In addition, is my Boolean statement correct?

I have already looked at the following:
[What is the reason behind "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290884/what-is-the-reason-behind-non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static)
[Why should the static field be accessed in a static way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642834/why-should-the-static-field-be-accessed-in-a-static-way)
Both of them do not help me understand what is incorrect.

There are 3 total programs. Airport.java, AirportClient.java and Pause.java.

AirportClient.java and Pause.java are pre-written. Airport.java is what I have filled in. The error resides in Airport.java, the other two files are to remain the same

Airport.java

```
public class Airport
{

  // instance variables
  private String airportCode;
  private int gates;

  // 1. ***** Add a static class variable *****
  //  countAirports is an int
  //  assign an initial value of 0

  private static int countAirports = 0;



  // 2. ***** Modify this method *****
  // Default constructor:
  // method name: Airport
  // return value:  none
  // parameters: none
  // function: sets the airportCode to an empty String
  //    ***** add 1 to countAirports class variable
  public Airport( )
  {
     airportCode = "";
     countAirports++;

  }

  // 3. ***** Modify this method *****
  // Overloaded constructor:
  // method name: Airport
  // return value: none
  // parameters:  a String airport code and an int startGates
  // function: assigns airportCode the value of the
  //      startAirportCode parameter;
  //      calls the setGates method,
  //      passing the startGates parameter
  //    ***** add 1 to countAirports class variable
  public Airport( String startAirportCode, int startGates )
  {
     airportCode = startAirportCode;
     setGates( startGates );
     countAirports++;

  }

  // Accessor method for the airportCode instance variable
  // method name: getAirportCode
  // return value: String
  // parameters: none
  // function: returns airportCode
  public String getAirportCode( )
  {
     return airportCode;
  }

  // Accessor method for the gates instance variable
  // method name: getGates
  // return value: int
  // parameters: none
  // function: returns gates
  public int getGates( )
  {
     return gates;
  }

  // 4. ***** Write this method *****
  // Accessor method for the countAirports class variable
  // method name: getCountAirports
  // return value: int
  // parameters: none
  // function: returns countAirports
  public int getCountAirports()
  {
    return countAirports;
  }




  // Mutator method for the airportCode instance variable
  // method name: setAirportCode
  // return value: void
  // parameters: String newAirportCode
  // function: assigns airportCode the value of the
  //                    newAirportCode parameter
  public void setAirportCode( String newAirportCode )
  {
     airportCode = newAirportCode;
  }

  // Mutator method for the gates instance variable
  // method name: setGates
  // return value:  void
  // parameters: int newGates
  // function: validates the newGates parameter.
  //   if newGates is greater than 0, sets gates to newGates;
  //   otherwise, prints an error message to System.err
  //   and does not change value of gates
  public void setGates( int newGates )
  {
     if ( newGates  >=  0 )
       gates = newGates;
     else
     {
       System.err.println( "Gates must be at least 0" );
       System.err.println( "Value of gates unchanged." );
     }
  }

  // 5. ***** Write this method *****
  // method name:  toString
  // return value: String
  // parameters: none
  // function:  returns a String that contains the airportCode
  //    and gates

  public String toString()
  {
    return "Airport code: " + airportCode + "; gates: " + gates ;
  }


  // 6. ***** Write this method *****
  // method name: equals
  // return value: boolean
  // parameter:  Airport object
  // function:  returns true if airportCode
  //     and gates in this object
  //    are equal to those in the parameter object;
  //    returns false otherwise

  public boolean equals( Object o )
  {
    if ( ! (o instanceof Airport))
      return false;
    else
    {
      Airport objAirport = ( Airport ) o;
      if (airportCode.equals(objAirport.airportCode)
            && gates == objAirport.gates)
        return true;
      else
        return false;
    }







   }
}// end of Airport class definition
```

This is the AirportClient.java

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class AirportClient extends JFrame
{
  String action1, action2;
  boolean firstTime = true;

  double animationPause = 6.0;     // 6 seconds between animations
  Airport airport1, airport2;  // declare Airport object references

  public void workWithAirports( )
  {
    animate( "Two airport object references declared:",
                   "Airport airport1, airport2;" );

    /* Instantiate airport1 using the overloaded constructor  */
    airport1 = new Airport( "IAD", 30 );
    animate( "Instantiated airport1 using overloaded constructor:",
                   "airport1 = new Airport( \"IAD\", 30 );" );

    /* Call toString() */
    animate( "Calling toString:",
                    "JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, airport1.toString( ) );" );
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, airport1.toString( ) );

    /*  Instantiate a second airport object using overloaded constructor*/
    airport2 = new Airport( "IAD", 30 );
    animate( "Instantiated airport2 using overloaded constructor:",
                   "airport2 = new Airport( \"IAD\", 30 );" );

    /* Get the value of countAirports */
    animate( "Getting the value of countAirports:",
                    "JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, \"countAirports is \" +"
                            + "  Airport.getCountAirports( ) );" );
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "countAirports is " +
                     Airport.getCountAirports( ) );

     /* Compare the two airport objects */
     animate( "Comparing airport1 and airport2 using the equality operator ",
                    " if ( airport1 ==  airport2 )..." );
     if ( airport1 ==  airport2 )
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "airport1 and airport2 are equal" );
     else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "airport1 and airport2 are not equal" );

     /* Compare the two Airport objects */
     animate( "Comparing airport1 and airport2 using equals:",
                       " if ( airport1.equals( airport2 ) )..." );
     if ( airport1.equals( airport2 ) )
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "airport1 and airport2 are equal" );
     else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "airport1 and airport2 are not equal" );

     /* Finished */
     animate( "Actions are complete, exiting", "" );
     System.exit( 1 );
   }

  public AirportClient( )
  {
    super( "Using the Airport Class" );
    setSize( 520, 400 );
    setVisible( true );
  }

  public void paint( Graphics g )
  {
    super.paint( g );
    if ( firstTime )
      firstTime = false;
    else
    {
      int boxL = 75, boxH = 20;
      int sX = 50, sY = 50;

      // countAirports
      g.setColor( Color.BLACK );
      g.drawRect( sX, sY, boxL, boxH );
      g.drawString( "countAirports", sX, sY - 10 );
      g.setColor( Color.BLUE );
      g.drawString( Integer.toString( Airport.getCountAirports( ) ),
                            sX + 15, sY + 15 );

      // airport1
      sY = 125;
      if ( airport1 != null )
      {
        // object reference box
        g.setColor( Color.BLACK );
        g.drawRect( sX, sY, boxL, boxH );
        g.drawString( "airport1", sX, sY - 10 );
        draw( g, sX, sY, airport1 ); // draw airport object
      }
      else
      {
        // indicate null reference
        g.setColor( Color.BLACK );
        g.drawRect( sX, sY, boxL, boxH );
        g.drawString( "airport1", sX, sY - 10 );
        g.setColor( Color.BLUE );
        g.drawString( "null", sX + 15, sY + 15 );
      }

      sY = 250;
      if ( airport2 != null )
      {
        // object reference box
        g.setColor( Color.BLACK );
        g.drawRect( sX, sY, boxL, boxH );
        g.drawString( "airport2", sX, sY - 10 );
        draw( g, sX, sY, airport2 ); // draw airport object
       }
       else
       {
         // indicate null reference
   g.setColor( Color.BLACK );
         g.drawRect( sX, sY, boxL, boxH );
         g.drawString( "airport2", sX, sY - 10 );
         g.setColor( Color.BLUE );
         g.drawString( "null", sX + 15, sY + 15 );
       }

       // display action at bottom of screen
       g.setColor( Color.BLUE );
       g.drawString( action1, 15, 370 );
       g.drawString( action2, 20, 385 );
    }
  }

  private void draw( Graphics g, int sX, int sY, Airport a )
  {
    int boxL = 75, boxH = 20;

    // arrow
    g.setColor( Color.BLACK );
    g.drawLine( sX + boxL, sY + boxH / 2,
                 sX + boxL + 25, sY + boxH / 2 );
    g.drawLine( sX + boxL + 25, sY + boxH / 2,
                 sX + boxL + 25, sY + boxH * 2 );
    g.drawLine( sX + boxL + 25 - 5, sY + boxH * 2 - 5,
                 sX + boxL + 25, sY + boxH * 2 );
    g.drawLine( sX + boxL + 25 + 5, sY + boxH * 2 - 5,
                 sX + boxL + 25, sY + boxH * 2 );

    // airportCode
    g.setColor( Color.BLACK );
    g.drawString( "airport code", sX + boxL - 75, sY + 2 * boxH + 15 );
    g.drawRect( sX + boxL, sY + 2 * boxH, boxL, boxH );
    g.setColor( Color.BLUE );
    g.drawString( a.getAirportCode( ),
                         sX + boxL + 5, sY + 2 * boxH + 15 );

    // gates
    g.setColor( Color.BLACK );
    g.drawString( "gates", sX + boxL - 75, sY + 3 * boxH + 15 );
    g.drawRect( sX + boxL, sY + 3 * boxH, boxL, boxH );
    g.setColor( Color.BLUE );
    g.drawString( Integer.toString( a.getGates( ) ),
                  sX + boxL + 5, sY + 3 * boxH + 15 );
  }

  private void animate( String a1, String a2 )
  {
    action1 = a1;
    action2 = a2;
    repaint( );
    Pause.wait( animationPause );
  }

  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    AirportClient app = new AirportClient( );
    app.workWithAirports( );
    app.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
  }
}
```

And Pause.java

```
public class Pause
{
  /** wait method
  *  @param seconds  number of seconds to pause
  */
  public static void wait( double seconds )
  {
     try
     {
       Thread.sleep( (int)( seconds * 1000 ) );
     }
     catch ( InterruptedException e )
     {
       e.printStackTrace( );
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post your entire code. Limit it to minimum which is needed to reproduce your problem (for more info visit: http://sscce.org/). You will get your answers faster and they will be less confusing for others to read. Also having multiple accounts in Stack Overflow is not allowed so don't repost same question from new accounts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33577464/non-static-method-cannont-be-referenced-from-a-static-context-where-does-the-er

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `static` method means that it's a method of the class, not a specific instance (Object) of that class. This is what your method should be (just add the `static` keyword to the method declaration.)

However, you're referencing it in a static way, when the declaration says that it's non-static. This is causing the error.

A non-static method means that it is called on *an instance* of the class --- it is not for the *class* itself.

For example, for `static`:

```
// if you're only manipulating something for the entire `Airport` class,
// independent of its objects, use a `static` method (or field, for that matter)
// in this case, you are not doing `getCountAirports()` ON a certain object
public static getCountAirports() { ... }
public static int countAirports = 0;

// and these can be referenced on the CLASS:
Airport.getCountAirports();
Airport.countAirports
```

For non-`static`:

```
// in this case, this is for a particular `Airport` instance:
public String getAirportCode() { ... }
public String airportCode;

// and this can be called on the OBJECT
Airport a = new Airport("JFK", 39);
a.getAirportCode();
a.airportCode;
```

Comment: Thanks, this explains my issue. I was missing a static within the access method for getCountAirports.

Comment: @SamBob I'm glad I helped (please accept?) And welcome to the SO community! Just try not to ask duplicates.