# Class instantiates instances,static is class specific, then why instances don't share static attribute?

Tags: java, oop, static

A `static` attribute is class specific, to me that means it is only an attribute of the class. I know that instances use instance variables. My question is, If I, say, create a class called `Animal` and create a static attribute called `live` (which makes sense because being live is a static attribute of Animal), then why it won't be for instances such as `dog`, `human`, but only the class `Animal`? They are all live too and here I can see instances are really sharing this static attribute `live`.

Please don't give me Java definition or Oracle document definition; I know all that. As a beginner I was wondering why it's not making sense in the literal terms.

Comment: "which makes sense because being live is a static attribute of Animal" no it's not every animal should have its own life, no? Some reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: If we're talking about living animals then they're all "live", aren't they?

Comment: So dogs are live, humans are live, and at the same time animal is live.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Animal {
  int age;
}
```

The above indicates that *every **instance** of Animal including instances of Animal's subclasses* has an `age`, and each one is separate: Animals can't see or affect one another's ages. Internally, when you call `new Animal()` or `new Dog()`, Java sets aside space in that instance for the `age`.

```
class Animal {
  static String kingdom = "Animalia";
}
```

This one, however, indicates that *the **class** named `Animal` has a property, exactly one, and it's called `Animal.kingdom`*. That `kingdom` property is available without an Animal instance, and (in a hierarchy where Dog extends Animal) it *appears* to be available as `Animal.kingdom`, `Dog.kingdom`, `someAnimalInstance.kingdom`, and `someDogInstance.kingdom`. However, all of these are provided as a courtesy: the official accessor is `Animal.kingdom`, and there's only ever one regardless of however many instances (including zero) you have of Animal or its subclasses.

**Related:** [Why should the static field be accessed in a static way?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5642834/1426891)